# static site generation platform for huge amounts of documentation

Tags: document-management, documentation-generator, knowledge-base, documentation-viewer, static-site-generator

At our company we have deployed several static file generators like [sphinx](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/), [docfx](https://dotnet.github.io/docfx/) or [docusaurus](https://docusaurus.io/). They are used by different departments and the goal is to get all on one platform.

We've tried to combine all departments under several of the most popular platforms, but they all seem to not be built for huge amounts of documentation. Either a build process is necessary, which takes way too long, or the auto generated navigation structure is hard to navigate under.

It is our desire to use a platform with as minimal customizations as possible. Do you know any platforms that are suited for this task?

Answer (score 0):

From what you say I think you need a **Knowledge Base**.

There are many and very different platforms for it, some combine features such as ticket management for customer support, shared mailbox or even chat, and even if you are not looking for a HelpDesk-type solution, it may be interesting to take a look.

Without wishing to be exhaustive, some of them are:

- [intercom.com](https://intercom.com)
- [tawk.to](https://tawk.to)
- [helpscout.com](https://helpscout.com)
- [helpdocs.io](https://helpdocs.io)

Other more specific KB solutions without so much extra can be:

- [nuclino.com](https://nuclino.com)
- [stonly.com](https://stonly.com)

Try to set the preferences you have and the benefits that are essential to make the right decision:

- integrations
- number of users/administrators
- custom domain
- variety of formats
- structure, classification and order
- restricted access
- price
- ...